# div колонка без прокрутки на странице

Tags: css, html

> На странице есть левая колонка и центральная. Как сделать так что бы при прокрутке информация на левои колонке оставалась фиксированной,а правая прокручивалась дальше.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> position: fixed; не помогает
>   левая колонка уезжает

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно еще `position: sticky;` применить, ну это так как дополнение к ответу `humster_spb`, но он работает несколько по другому...

```css
.left {
  width: 100px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  float: left;
  top: 0;
  position: sticky;
}

.right {
  width: 200px;
  height: 1500px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: 130px;
}

.top {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="top">
  top
</div>

<div class="left">
  Информация в левой колонке
</div>

<div class="right">
  <br/>ffffffffffffff
  <br/>ffffffffffffff
  <br/>ffffffffffffff
  <br/>ffffffffffffff
  <br/>ffffffffffffff
  <br/>ffffffffffffff
  <br/>ffffffffffffff
  <br/>ffffffffffffff
  <br/>ffffffffffffff
  <br/>ffffffffffffff
  <br/>ffffffffffffff
  <br/>ffffffffffffff
  <br/>ffffffffffffff
  <br/>ffffffffffffff
  <br/>ffffffffffffff
  <br/>ffffffffffffff
  <br/>ffffffffffffff
  <br/>ffffffffffffff
  <br/>ffffffffffffff
  <br/>ffffffffffffff
  <br/>ffffffffffffff
  <br/>ffffffffffffff
  <br/>ffffffffffffff
  <br/>ffffffffffffff
  <br/>ffffffffffffff
  <br/>ffffffffffffff
  <br/>ffffffffffffff
  <br/>ffffffffffffff
  <br/>ffffffffffffff
  <br/>ffffffffffffff
  <br/>ffffffffffffff
  <br/>ffffffffffffff
  <br/>ffffffffffffff
  <br/>ffffffffffffff
  <br/>ffffffffffffff
  <br/>ffffffffffffff

</div>
```

Comment: в моем случае не работает...

Comment: добавила position: fixed;top: 0;height: 300px; почти заработало но наезжает на верхнюю шапку

Comment: ну может код стоит выложить?

Comment: sticky, кстати, классная тема, да - плюсанул Вам за этот вариант. жаль, с поддержкой браузеров плоховато

Comment: Спасибо за ответы!!! Ваши примеры работают,свои код буду переделывать заново.

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста...

Comment: @humster_spb, ну да с `IE`  не дружит...

Answer (score 5):

Как это position: fixed не помогает? Вот же:

```css
.left {
  width: 100px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  float: left;
  position: fixed;
}

.right {
  width: 200px;
  height: 1500px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: 130px;
}
```

```html
<div class="left">
Информация в левой колонке
</div>

<div class="right">

</div>
```

Comment: у меня все через id сделано

Comment: @Лиана, и что? причём тут id? :))

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/t3wh7ovx/4/ тут исходный код

Comment: пыталась id и class вместе задать,тоже не вышло

Comment: @Лиана, ну и в чём проблема? добавляете #left position:fixed, а #text - margin-left: 250px (чтобы не наслаивалось одно на другое) - https://jsfiddle.net/t3wh7ovx/7/

Comment: посмотрите я добавила картинку в описании,левая колонка зафиксировалась как-то не так

Comment: @Лиана, по картинке я гадать не умею :)) Возможно, надо задать top: 0 (или не 0, а высоту шапки). Приведите код, чтобы было видно, что именно толкает левый блок вниз.

Answer (score 1):

Работает `position: fixed`

```css
.container, .left, .right {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  position: relative;
}

.container {
  background-color: gray;
  width: 900px;
  height: 550px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.left, .right {
  background-color: white;
}

.left {
  width: 200px;
  height: 500px;
  float: left;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: auto;
}

.right {
  margin-left: 5px;
  width: calc(100% - 230px);
  height: 540px;
  left: 212px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
</div>
```

Пример на [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/globadaniil/gowd00v6/21/)

Comment: ну, я ж уже дал такой ответ - зачем дублировать? :)

Comment: Пока в фиддле делал, не заметил ответа. Думаете, стоит удалить?

Comment: да мне-то он не мешает )) я просто удивился